# Server with Nodejs and client with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: node.js, server, xmlhttprequest, client

I have this server.js

```
var http = require('http');

const PORT = 8000;

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    var msg = req.url.split('/')[1];
    console.log('Recieved: ' + msg);
    var html = '<h3>You sent: ' + msg + '</h3>';
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    res.write(html);
    res.end();
    if (msg == 'end') process.exit();
}).listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("Server listening on: %s", PORT);
});
```

and this client.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <textarea id="textArea" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button onclick=" document.getElementById('textArea').value = '' ">clear</button>
    <button onclick="sendToServer(document.getElementById('textArea').value)">send</button>
    <br>
    <p id="display"></p>

    <script>
    function sendToServer(data) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:8000/" + data, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The server recieves the data from the client and print it on console.
But I have a problem when the server sends the html string to the client. The client doesn't recieve the html string from the server.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest looking in the network tab of the Chrome debugger and see what is actually being returned back from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a problem with **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**

That is why  - you have exception on client side

Try to replace this (on server script)

```
 res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
```

to this

```
res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"});
```

Comment: @giovanni_ You're welcome. If question resolved, please - set it as answered